# Save the state of listview when the application closes (after turning the screen)

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences, savestate

I need to save the state of listview when the application closes (after turning the screen). SQL does not want to use. I know that there are standard methods: SharedPreferences, onSaveInstanceState. My code is:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //-----------listitem------------
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    catnames = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catnames);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

And put Adapter

```
catnames.add(0, name);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Maybe I should not use ArrayAdapter? Help please ... 
I want to save catnames)
ps application extends SherlockActivity.

Comment: What do you consider 'the state'? At turning the screen your activity is destroid and newly created but your application continues to run. It does not close. What do you want exactly?

Comment: Condition listview. I fill it. After closing the application, my listview should save its state.

Comment: @Yaroslav If I understand right, you want the listview to look exactly as it is after the screen is on as when it was turned off ?

Comment: If you don't want to use SQLite and your data storage strategy is simple, go for shared preferences.

Comment: Yes. Save state after close application...

Comment: @EngrAnum Bundle ? :)

Comment: Don't you want to save the state before closing the application? So 'the state' is 'the condition'. And what is 'the condition'?

Comment: want to save the state before closing the application:)

Comment: @Yaroslav The question is what do you mean when you say "state" ? Does it mean the way the list looks to the user ? :)

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/aqsshziqn/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `SQLite` datababse to persist the data. When the application closes, save the data to the database. When the application starts, retrieve the data from the database. All you need to learn is simple SQL :)

This should give you a head start: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

**Update:**
If you are looking to use `onSavedInstanceState()` then  you need to use `Bundle`s which are, in simple terms, key-value pairs.

Once you get your adapter to populate the data, just use the `setSelection()` or the `smoothScrollToPosition()` to go to the element you want. This implies that you current position of the list when your screen goes off. For that, you need the `getFirstVisiblePosition()` method. This will be saved in your `Bundle` and this is what you will use when your screen comes back on.

Comment: Thanks :) But I would like to see the method without the use of SQL :)

Comment: I understand, but I would like to see an example :)

Comment: @Yaroslav [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) for Android is difficult. You will have to search SO or other sites and modify the examples to suit your need :)

Comment: Still have to use SQL ... lost a lot of time to look for alternative methods ... but none of them worked ...

Comment: @Yaroslav If you were a little clearer on what you mean by the "state", we could have helped better :)

Comment: Quite funny that both are unclear about what has to be saved. One speaks about data and the other of state and condition. Yaroslav why don't you tell that you want to save the catnames?

Comment: You can do that in sharedPreferences or in a file or sql database. The choice is up to you. But if i were you i would start to put it in savedInstanceState to accomodate for when you turn the device.